# How add a css class with php to a string already containing the element?

Tags: php, html, css

I have this object item `$activities->action` containing a string, like so:

```
["action"]=> string() "<a href="link">user070</a> posted an update <a href="linkitem">here</a>
```

The html element is already defined so I can't / don't know how to add a CSS class here.

How would I add a CSS class here with PHP on the first link?

And how could I add a css class to the second link if I wanted?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You mean... you don't have the source code where this link has been defined?

Comment: Can you wrap a `div` around it and apply the class to the wrapper instead?

Comment: I can but I need the class on the link in the string, not the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

```
["action"]=> string() "<a href="link">user070</a> posted an update <a href="linkitem" class="someClass">here</a>
```

Or is there more you need than that?

Comment: yes this is what I need, but how do I add that class in that string with php?

Comment: Why do you need php? You can simply edit as I've shown. I guess I don't understand what you're asking of the above doesn't work for you. Is there more code to this you haven't shown?